# Meromorphic Functions - Definition Confusion, why is this an equivalence?

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, meromorphic-functions

From [Terrence Tao's Blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/10/11/math-246a-notes-4-singularities-of-holomorphic-functions/):

[image]

I don't see how this define an equivalence. $f_1 $ ~ $f_2$ , $f_2$ ~ $f_3$ implies $f_1$ and $f_3$ coincide on $U\setminus (S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3)$ and not $U\setminus (S_1 \cup S_3)$? This doesn't satisfy definition of equivalence?

(By the way, how do I rescale the image?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've pointed out, it turns out that this fact is not completely trivial. It relies on the fact that meromorphic functions are continuous and are defined everywhere except on a discrete set. If $f_1$ and $f_2$ agree in this sense and $f_2$ and $f_3$ agree, it seems like there may be a point $z$ where $f_2$ is not defined but $f_1$ and $f_3$ are, and $f_1(z)\neq f_3(z)$. But this is not possible because
$$f_1(z)=\lim_{z'\to z}{f_1(z')}=\lim_{z'\to z}{f_3(z')}=f_3(z)$$
The equality in the middle is true because $f_1$ and $f_3$ agree on every point in a punctured neighborhood of $z$.